# SharePoint 2013 Set Yes/No field on selected list items (if/else) use JS

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint

In SharePoint, The discussion list, I'm created button "fix / unfix" (Yes/No type field) discussion. But the script only works the second time and subsequent times. This script checks the value 0 or 1 and changes to the opposite.
I'm not very good at scripting, so please show what is my mistake.

```
 function fieldTest() {
          var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
          var olist = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('discussion');
          var oitem = olist.getItemById(1);
          ctx.load(oitem, "fix");
          ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    check = oitem.get_item("fix");
                    if (!check) {
                             oitem.set_item("fix", true);
                    }
                    else {
                             oitem.set_item("fix", false);
                    }
                    oitem.update();    
                    });  
}
```

**UPDATE**
I was given the correct answer to the link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278081/sharepoint-2013-set-yes-no-field-on-selected-list-items-if-else-use-js

```
function fieldTest() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var olist = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Discussions List');
    var oitem = olist.getItemById(1);
    ctx.load(oitem, "fix");
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
              check = oitem.get_item("fix");
              if (!check) {
                       oitem.set_item("fix", true);
              }
              else {
                       oitem.set_item("fix", false);
              }
              oitem.update();  
              ctx.executeQueryAsync();
                    });  
}
```

need add another "**executeQuery**" after "**oitem.update();**".
Thanks Rune Sperre!!!